# How to define sorting custom tie-breaking rule in Python?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement an algorithm using max heap to solve the skyline problem: compare two x,y-dimensions of buildings, and resolve ties as per [the following Java code](https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/geometry/SkylineDrawing.java):

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(BuildingPoint o) {
        //first compare by x.
        //If they are same then use this logic
        //if two starts are compared then higher height building should be picked first
        //if two ends are compared then lower height building should be picked first
        //if one start and end is compared then start should appear before end
        if (this.x != o.x) {
            return this.x - o.x;
        } else {
            return (this.isStart ? -this.height : this.height) - (o.isStart ? -o.height : o.height);
        }
    }
```

How do I implement that in Python? I know I can specify the `key` parameter in the `sorted()` function but I'm not sure how to go about this example.

```
# Examples (s = start, e = end):

Input = [[0,2,'s'], [0,3,'s'], [1,2,'e'], [1,3,'e']]
output = [[0,3,'s'], [0,2,'s'], [1,2,'e'], [1,3,'e']]

Input = [[4,2,'s'], [3,3,'s'], [5,3,'e'], [5,2,'e']]
output = [[3,3,'s'], [4,2,'s'], [5,2,'e'], [5,3,'e']]

Input = [[7,3,'s'], [8,3,'e']], [6,2,'s'], [7,2,'e']
output = [[6,2,'s'], [7,3,'s'], [7,2,'e'], [8,3,'e']]
```

Comment: Input? Expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Updated!

Comment: Okay. This is pretty clear. One question though, what are the first two numbers? Are both of them important when sorting? Or, is it just one of them.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ first number is x coordinate and second number is y coordinate - yes, both are important.

Comment: Ok let's call your input `xs1, ys1, xs2, ys2, xe1, ye1, xe2, ye2`. No need for the 's', 'e' labels. Use `Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])` to make things clearer.